# how to get an array of column configurations in Kendo grid angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

suppose i've the following kendo grid

```
 <kendo-grid-column field="full_name" title="Contact Name" [width]="220">
              <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                <div
                  class="customer-photo"
                  [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': photoURL(dataItem) }"
                ></div>
                <div class="customer-name">{{ dataItem.full_name }}</div>
              </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="job_title" title="Job Title" [width]="220">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column
              field="country"
              title="Country"
              [width]="100"
              [class]="{ 'text-center': true }"
              [resizable]="false"
            >
              <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                <img class="flag" [src]="flagURL(dataItem)" width="30" />
              </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
```

what i want to do is to get an array of grid columns with column title & field name

eg: [{field:"full_name",title:"Contact Name"},
{field:"job_title",title:"Job Title"}];

how to do this in Kendo Grid for angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the grid using `ViewChild` and then access its `columns` field:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GridComponent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-grid";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-grid #grid [data]="gridData">
            <kendo-grid-column field="Id" title="ID">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="CompanyName" title="Company Name">
            </kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
    `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild("grid") grid: GridComponent;

    public readonly gridData = [{
        'Id': 'ALFKI',
        'CompanyName': 'Alfreds Futterkiste',
        'ContactName': 'Maria Anders',
        'ContactTitle': 'Sales Representative',
        'City': 'Berlin'
    }, {
        'Id': 'ANATR',
        'CompanyName': 'Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados',
        'ContactName': 'Ana Trujillo',
        'ContactTitle': 'Owner',
        'City': 'México D.F.'
    }, {
        'Id': 'ANTON',
        'CompanyName': 'Antonio Moreno Taquería',
        'ContactName': 'Antonio Moreno',
        'ContactTitle': 'Owner',
        'City': 'México D.F.'
    }];

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const columns = this.grid.columns.map((column) => {
            return {
                field: column.field,
                title: column.title
            };
        });

        console.log(columns);
    }
}
```

**Note:** `this.grid.columns` gives you an object of type `QueryList<ColumnBase>`. The `ColumnBase` class doesn't contain the `field` field in its definition, however, it does appear on the object. I guess that `this.grid.columns` actually returns an object of type `QueryList<ColumnComponent>`. `ColumnComponent` derives from `ColumnBase` and does contain the `field` field.

Answer (score -2):

For me, to get the `column.filed`, the above code didn't work. But when I use `fieldName: column["field"]`, it worked for me.